# parse special json format with python

Tags: python, json

I want to get GPSLatitude and GPSLongitude value, but I can't use python position because the position is pretty random. I get the value by tag's value, how can I do that?

```
jsonFlickrApi({ "photo": { "id": "8566959299", "secret": "141af38562", "server": "8233", "farm": 9, "camera": "Apple iPhone 4S", 
    "exif": [
      { "tagspace": "JFIF", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "JFIFVersion", "label": "JFIFVersion", 
        "raw": { "_content": 1.01 } },
      { "tagspace": "JFIF", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "ResolutionUnit", "label": "Resolution Unit", 
        "raw": { "_content": "inches" } },
      { "tagspace": "JFIF", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "XResolution", "label": "X-Resolution", 
        "raw": { "_content": 72 }, 
        "clean": { "_content": "72 dpi" } },
      { "tagspace": "JFIF", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "YResolution", "label": "Y-Resolution", 
        "raw": { "_content": 72 }, 
        "clean": { "_content": "72 dpi" } },
      { "tagspace": "GPS", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "GPSLatitudeRef", "label": "GPS Latitude Ref", 
        "raw": { "_content": "North" } },
      { "tagspace": "GPS", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "GPSLatitude", "label": "GPS Latitude", 
        "raw": { "_content": "39 deg 56' 44.40\"" }, 
        "clean": { "_content": "39 deg 56' 44.40\" N" } },
      { "tagspace": "GPS", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "GPSLongitudeRef", "label": "GPS Longitude Ref", 
        "raw": { "_content": "East" } },
      { "tagspace": "GPS", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "GPSLongitude", "label": "GPS Longitude", 
        "raw": { "_content": "116 deg 16' 10.20\"" }, 
        "clean": { "_content": "116 deg 16' 10.20\" E" } },
    ] }, "stat": "ok" })
```

Comment: Have you tried iterating over them?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that's the last thing I want to try, is it very time/cpu consuming to iter over? so stilling looking for a better way, or maybe iterating is the best way, i am not sure.

Comment: Is the comma just before the last closing bracket `]` actually there, or is that a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: @OliverW. it is there: here is the flickr api test page: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.getExif

Comment: Thank you for that link - convenient! But, I'm not [seeing a comma](https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getExif&api_key=88341066e8f0a40516599d28d8170627&photo_id=8566959299&secret=141af38562&format=json) just before the closing bracket though (and the output wouldn't be valid json if it were there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the exception of the last comma just before the closing bracket `]`, the entire object returned by the FlickrAPI is [valid json](http://www.json.org/).

Assuming that that comma is merely a copy-paste error ([example evidence](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html) suggests this is the case), then the builtin [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) still won't be usable as is. That's because even though a string like `"116 deg 16' 10.20\" E"` is [valid json](http://www.json.org/string.gif), python's json module will complain with a ValueError because the double quote `"` isn't sufficiently quoted:

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{"a": "2"}')
{u'a': u'2'}
>>> json.loads('{"a": "2\""}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 10 (char 9)
```

The solution is to add another escaping backslash:

```
>>> json.loads('{"a": "2\\""}')
{u'a': u'2"'}
```

For your full `jsonFlickrApi` response, you could add those extra backslashes with the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> response = """jsonFlickrApi({ "photo": { "id": "8566959299", "secret": "141af38562", "server": "8233", "farm": 9, "camera": "Apple iPhone 4S", 
...     "exif": [
...       { "tagspace": "JFIF", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "JFIFVersion", "label": "JFIFVersion", 
...         "raw": { "_content": 1.01 } },
...       { "tagspace": "JFIF", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "ResolutionUnit", "label": "Resolution Unit", 
...         "raw": { "_content": "inches" } },
...       { "tagspace": "JFIF", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "XResolution", "label": "X-Resolution", 
...         "raw": { "_content": 72 }, 
...         "clean": { "_content": "72 dpi" } },
...       { "tagspace": "JFIF", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "YResolution", "label": "Y-Resolution", 
...         "raw": { "_content": 72 }, 
...         "clean": { "_content": "72 dpi" } },
...       { "tagspace": "GPS", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "GPSLatitudeRef", "label": "GPS Latitude Ref", 
...         "raw": { "_content": "North" } },
...       { "tagspace": "GPS", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "GPSLatitude", "label": "GPS Latitude", 
...         "raw": { "_content": "39 deg 56' 44.40\"" }, 
...         "clean": { "_content": "39 deg 56' 44.40\" N" } },
...       { "tagspace": "GPS", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "GPSLongitudeRef", "label": "GPS Longitude Ref", 
...         "raw": { "_content": "East" } },
...       { "tagspace": "GPS", "tagspaceid": 0, "tag": "GPSLongitude", "label": "GPS Longitude", 
...         "raw": { "_content": "116 deg 16' 10.20\"" }, 
...         "clean": { "_content": "116 deg 16' 10.20\" E" } }
...     ] }, "stat": "ok" })"""
>>> quoted_resp = re.sub('deg ([^"]+)"', r'deg \1\\"', response[14:-1])
```

That quoted response can then be used in a call to `json.loads` and you can then easily access the required data in the newly generated dictionary structure:

```
>>> photodict = json.loads(quoted_resp)
>>> for meta in photodict['photo']['exif']:                                                                                                               
...     if meta["tagspace"] == "GPS" and meta["tag"] == "GPSLongitude":
...         print(meta["clean"]["_content"])
... 
116 deg 16' 10.20" E
```

Comment: The API allows the client to request standard JSON rather than the JSONP posted by the OP. This avoids stripping of the JSONP function wrapper  `jsonFlickrApi() `. Also, the actual response is properly escaped (I think the OP has not posted the original response) so the regex backslash escape is unnecessary.

Comment: @mhawke thank you for the explanation, I had no working experience with the API. And thank you for posting a full example: upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say whether you using one of the Flickr APIs; I assume not because handling JSON responses is trivial if you are using an API such as [flickrapi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flickrapi).

```
import flickrapi

api_key = '88341066e8f0a40516599d28d8170627'   # from flickr's API explorer
secret = 'sssshhhh'
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, secret, format='parsed-json')
response = flickr.photos.getExif(photo_id='8566959299')
lat_long = {exif['tag']: exif['clean']['_content']
                    for exif in response['photo']['exif']
                        if exif['tag'] in (u'GPSLongitude', u'GPSLatitude')}

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(lat_long)
{u'GPSLatitude': u'39 deg 56\' 44.40" N',
 u'GPSLongitude': u'116 deg 16\' 10.20" E'}
```

---

But continuing with the assumption that you are not using an API, the response format that you are seeing is actually [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which is better suited to Javascript than it is Python. You can, however, request a response in JSON representation that does not have the enclosing `jsonFlickrApi()` function wrapper. Do this by specifying `format=json&nojsoncallback=1` in the query parameters of the request. Using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) library makes requesting and parsing the JSON response easy, but this will work just as well with `urllib2.urlopen()` combined with `json.loads()` if you can't use `requests` e.g.

```
import requests

params = {'api_key': '88341066e8f0a40516599d28d8170627',
          'api_sig': '7b2dcfb2cd3a747179c2ed0fdc492699',
          'format': 'json',
          'method': 'flickr.photos.getExif',
          'nojsoncallback': '1',
          'photo_id': '8566959299',
          'secret': 'sssshhhh'}    
response = requests.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/', params=params)
data = response.json()
lat_long = {exif['tag']: exif['clean']['_content']
                for exif in data['photo']['exif']
                    if exif['tag'] in (u'GPSLongitude', u'GPSLatitude')}

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(lat_long)
{u'GPSLatitude': u'39 deg 56\' 44.40" N',
 u'GPSLongitude': u'116 deg 16\' 10.20" E'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If looking at the whole string as `jsonFlickrApi(XXX)`, `XXX` is a standard JSON string. With `json` library, `XXX` can be converted to python dictionary and then parsed easily.